# Percentage for each row as a new column

Tags: r

i have this data frame

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c("a","b","c","d","e"))
```

I want to add a column where it shows the percentage of the total sum for column x.

So it can look like this:

```
dat_percent <- data.frame(x=c(1:5), y=c("a","b","c","d","e"), z=c(7,13,20,27,33))
```

I know it must be very basic stuff, but i can't come up with a solution.

Thanks

Comment: `dat$z <- dat$x/sum(dat$x)*100` If you need to, you can use `round` to achieve what you show as the desired result.

Comment: thanks Roland, yor solution was good.